# PHP Zend Hash Vulnerability Exploitation Vector

Tags: php, cms, drupal, exploit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CVE-2007-5416 PHP Zend Hash Vulnerability Exploitation Vector (Drupal)](https://superuser.com/questions/477773/cve-2007-5416-php-zend-hash-vulnerability-exploitation-vector-drupal)

According to exploit-db, http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/4510/, it says the following:

Example: http://www.example.com/drupal/?_menu[callbacks][1][callback]=drupal_eval&_menu[items][][type]=-1&-312030023=1&q=1/

What are "[callbacks]","[1]" and all these stuffs? What should I put in to these stuffs?

Can anyone present a real possible example?

I wasn't asking for a real website; I was asking for a possible example! So, how would address be like - what should I put in to these stuffs, as the question says..

Comment: @John I re-posted, because the reason given for closing the post was not the intention I intended. I flagged the post, but there just seemed to be no response.

Comment: It would have been good not to use another user account for posting the question. Also, your flag was declined – check in your profile – simply for the reason that the question is still off topic (regarding CMS). Your question might be on topic for [Drupal.SE], but I can't promise. You will have to check their FAQ or Meta site in case of doubt. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What is a callback?

Answer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_science%29).

Examples of real Drupal callbacks?

Many [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/callback).

That's as far as I am willing to go.